# Should I be using a PUT or POST in this situation?

Tags: http, rest

A server side service is populating the database. I send a http request from my application with some metadata information from the document and I want the server side service to generate a unique uuid for this document and populate the db with the doc uuid and metadata and send back the uuid to me. Should the client be executing a PUT request in this case or a POST. I only want one record of the document metadata and uuid generated for it.

Answer (score 2):

PUT is generally used to overwrite and replace or create a resource.

I think that is what you should be using here. For example:

```
PUT /document/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

And have it return a UUID and metadata for the document.

And quoting from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest):

> I think one cannot stress enough the fact that PUT is idempotent: if
>   the network is botched and the client is not sure whether his request
>   made it through, it can just send it a second (or 100th) time, and it
>   is guaranteed by the HTTP spec that this has exactly the same effect
>   as sending once.